# How to simply load of CLOB

Tags: xml, oracle11g, clob

The following allows me to parse an XML file fine but I am wondering how to simplify the syntax to not require the clob_pointer.txt file and to specify the xml directly.  I tried location(XMLDIR:'XYZ.XML') but that didn't work.

```
DROP TABLE EXT_CLOB_TABLE;
CREATE TABLE EXT_CLOB_TABLE
(
    CLOB_CONTENT CLOB
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY XMLDIR
    ACCESS PARAMETERS
(
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(
  CLOB_POINTER CHAR(200)
)
COLUMN TRANSFORMS (CLOB_CONTENT FROM LOBFILE(CLOB_POINTER) FROM (XMLDIR) 
CLOB)
)
   LOCATION('clob_pointer.txt')
);


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ext_xml_view
AS
SELECT xmltype(CLOB_CONTENT) xml FROM ext_clob_table;  

SELECT * FROM ext_xml_view;
```

I tried changing the location to:

```
location(XMLDIR:'XYZ.XML')
```

But get the following errors;

> ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout ORA-29400:
>   data cartridge error error opening file
>   /u01/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/db/rdbms/xml/
>   29913. 00000 -  "error in executing %s callout"
>   *Cause:    The execution of the specified callout caused an error.
>   *Action:   Examine the error messages take appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your XML file is named `clob_pointer.txt`, then you could use (something along the lines of)

```
select
    xmltype(
        xmlData => bfilename('XMLDIR', 'clob_pointer.txt'),
        csid => nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')
    )
from dual;
```

The `sys.xmltype` has a constructor accepting a `bfile` locator. Of course, since it can't know of the charset used in your file, as it's a binary file for Oracle in this case, you also have to supply the character set identifier into the `csid` argument.